# Existing style also apply on link

Tags: html, css

There are lot of small articles showing in page. I have already style headings of article but they are showing only a text now.  Now when i apply anchor tag for making this as a link then the color of the heading is changed. The headings and text save in a database means it will show whatever is in the database.

Now what i want is the color of the heading would be same as i styled and the heading would be link..

Code:

```
<a href="localhost/article.php"><p class="heading"> Hello World </p></a>
```

CSS:

```
.heading:nth-child(7n+1) {
    color: #black;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

EDIT:

```
 .heading:nth-child(7n+1) a {
        color: #black;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

 .heading:nth-child(7n+2) a {
        color: #Grey;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: your question is a little unclear. Why did you put :nth-child(7+1) in the css rule?

Comment: Actually thats my code.. I applied nth child for repeating the colors after 7 posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you need to color the `a` element in black.

I suggest to change the html this way:

```
<p class="heading"><a href="localhost/article.php"> Hello World </a></p>
```

and to add the tag selector to your existing selector in the css rule:

```
.heading:nth-child(7n+1), .heading:nth-child(7n+1) a {
    color: black;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Well correct me if am wrong here ..
here <a> color only applies it here with .heading class here not every <a> in a page right .?

Comment: Yes, i appies only to the a elements that are childs of heading.

Comment: I just edit the question.. now first the heading <a> color applies only black and the second one is grety. right .? It only applies in this heading not all the <a> in a page right .?

Answer (score 0):

First, having a block element (p) inside an inline element is incorrect. Use a span instead of p.

Then, it 's hard to understand your CSS rule (7n+1) with this short fragment of code.

Comment: In HTML 4.x (and earlier) and XHTML 1.x — No. <a> elements may not contain <p> elements.

In HTML 5 — <a> elements may contain <p> elements, but browsers are a bit flaky about it and you may find you have to explicitly set the <a> to display: block in your stylesheet.

The code in the question also includes an <a> inside that <p>. This is not allowed. An <a> element may not be a descendant of another <a> element.